# Color in Spherical3DPlot according to value

Tags: plotting, color

I want to colour a 3D plot according to it's value. I could only mange in one direction (say in 'z' direction) but I want to show them in all direction together. I have written the following code:

```
cf = ColorData["Rainbow"];
plot = SphericalPlot3D[
  1/((Sin[\[Theta]]^4*
       Cos[\[Phi]]^4*0.049896792) + (2*(Sin[\[Theta]]*
         Cos[\[Phi]])^2*(Sin[\[Theta]]*
         Sin[\[Phi]])^2*(-0.01555592)) + (2*(Sin[\[Theta]]*
         Cos[\[Phi]])^2*(Cos[\[Theta]])^2*(-0.030833372)) + (Sin[\
\[Theta]]^4*
       Sin[\[Phi]]^4*0.011343866) + (2*(Sin[\[Theta]]*
         Sin[\[Phi]])^2*(Cos[\[Theta]])^2*(0.007005355)) + (Cos[\
\[Theta]]^4*0.025839216) + ((Sin[\[Theta]]*
         Sin[\[Phi]])^2*(Cos[\[Theta]])^2*(0.01848854)) + ((Sin[\
\[Theta]]*
         Cos[\[Phi]])^2*(Cos[\[Theta]])^2*(0.020627753)) + ((Sin[\
\[Theta]]*Cos[\[Phi]])^2*(Sin[\[Theta]]*
         Sin[\[Phi]])^2*(0.031580823))), {\[Theta], 
   0, \[Pi]}, {\[Phi], 0, 2 \[Pi]}, 
  ColorFunction -> (cf@Rescale[#3, {0, 100}] &), Axes -> True, 
  ColorFunctionScaling -> False]
```

And here is the output I got:

[image]

I am using Mathematica 8 version and my desire output would be something like (forget about the shape, picture is just for understanding. I want the color description) shown below:

[image]

Comment: Try `ColorFunction -> (ColorData["Rainbow", #6] &)` (without the `ColorFunctionScaling` setting). [This is in the docs...](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SphericalPlot3D.html#796437997)

Comment: @J.M.: Nice!! I couldn't think about this smart way. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `ColorFunction` for `SphericalPlot3D` takes 6 arguments, referring to the Cartesian and spherical coordinates.

```
cf = ColorData["Rainbow"];
plot = SphericalPlot3D[
    1/((Sin[θ]^4*
         Cos[ϕ]^4*0.049896792) + (2*(Sin[θ]*
            Cos[ϕ])^2*(Sin[θ]*
            Sin[ϕ])^2*(-0.01555592)) + (2*(Sin[θ]*
            Cos[ϕ])^2*(Cos[θ])^2*(-0.030833372)) + (Sin[θ]^4*
         Sin[ϕ]^4*0.011343866) + (2*(Sin[θ]*
            Sin[ϕ])^2*(Cos[θ])^2*(0.007005355)) + (Cos[θ]^4*0.025839216) + ((Sin[θ]*
            Sin[ϕ])^2*(Cos[θ])^2*(0.01848854)) + ((Sin[θ]*
            Cos[ϕ])^2*(Cos[θ])^2*(0.020627753)) + ((Sin[θ]*Cos[ϕ])^2*(Sin[θ]*
            Sin[ϕ])^2*(0.031580823))), 
    {θ, 0, π}, {ϕ, 0, 2 π}, 
    ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z, θ, ϕ, r}, cf@#], 
    Axes -> True] & /@ {x, y, z, θ, ϕ, r}
```

[image]

I *think* you want the last one, scaling by `r`.

Comment: Jason, I edited your text as it implied that `ColorFunction` only took one argument.

Comment: @JasonB: Thank you so much for your quick reply. Yes, you got the right one.

Comment: @rcollyer Thanks for clarifying the post, I do get a bit sloppy at the end of the workday